# jQueryUI dialog is breaking my page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to load a page into the `.dialog()` feature of jQueryUI, which works fine.  But after closing the dialog box, the rest of my page is still disabled.

```
$(function() {
    var w = $(document).width();
    var h = $(document).height();

    $( "#diag" ).dialog({   //dialog box settings
        autoOpen: false,        //do not open automatically
        show: { 
            effect: "slide"     //slide frame in
        },
        modal: true,            //disable the other elements
        width: w,               //set width to window width
        height: h               //set width to window height
    });

    $( ".icon" ).click(function() { //on .icon click
        var v = $(this).attr('value'); //load value of clicked item into v
        $( "#diag" ).load(v).dialog( "open" ); //open the #diag box
    });
});
```

When I take away the `.load(v)` and comment out the initialization of v, `.dialog()` works perfectly.  I'm stumped.

Comment: Does the page you are loading in include another copy of jQuery and jQuery UI?

Comment: It did not.  I included it, retested and it got me a step closer!  Now when back to the main page, hover overs work.  Still am not able to re-open the window without refreshing.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably that `.load` asynchronously replaces the content, so you may be losing all of the event binding that properly dismisses the dialog.

Try this instead:

```
var v = $(this).attr('value');
var dialogContent = $('#diag');
dialogContent.load(v, function() {
    dialogContent.dialog('open');
});
```

In other words, wait for the load to complete before opening the dialog.

Comment: Kevin's hunch looks very likely as well.

Comment: This was a no-go :(

So, my button value that I am pulling is holding the file name.  It is loading the dialog correctly.  It's just after closing it, I have to refresh the page in order to re-open the same dialog box I just closed.

Comment: How are you closing the dialog? Maybe the problem lies in that code.

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/51wluW7)

I am using the "X" in the upper right of the dialog.  It seemed to be default.  Don't worry, thats fake data in the table.

Comment: Are you getting any JS errors when closing that are preventing the dialog from finishing its close process?

Comment: no errors until I try to re-open the dialog, which it gives me:
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open' jquery.min.js:3

Comment: Ah, perhaps the content you're loading contains the `diag` id and that's breaking your selector. `load` doesn't replace the selection, but replaces its inner content. Make sure you're not duplicating that `id`; otherwise `$('#diag')` may be matching two divs and showing the modal backdrop twice.

Comment: That error is what you get if you try to call a `.dialog('open')` method before you've done `$(el).dialog({ options })`

Comment: @Alnitak At first I did not get what you meant, but you just solved my problem.  Thank you!

For anyone who is curious, I moved the variables and settings to inside the click function.

Answer (score 0):

Moved everything inside of the the click function made everything work properly.  Thank you for the help everyone.

```
$(function() {
$( ".icon" ).click(function() {  //on .icon click
    var w = $(document).width();
    var h = $(document).height();

    $( "#diag" ).dialog({   //dialog box settings
       show: {  
       effect: "slide"      //slide frame in
       },
       modal: true,         //disable the other elements
       width: w,            //set width to window width
       height: h                //set width to window height
});
    var v = $(this).attr('value');  //load value of clicked item into v
$( "#diag" ).load(v).dialog( "open" );      //open the #diag box
});

});
```